# How to adjust a logo on my latex cv header

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am making this cv in latex using an altacv template. I want to add this logo to the top right of the document in the same line as my name but I can't figure out how to do that. The pdf currently looks like this:

[image: pdf pic]

and this is the code for this part

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}


% If using pdflatex:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}


\begin{document}

\name{Osama Younus}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.15in, height=.40in, right]{lums.png}
\end{figure}
\tagline{Software Developer}

\personalinfo{%
  \email{21100013@lums.edu.pk }
  \phone{--------------}
  \linkedin{https://www.linkedin.com/in/osamayounus20/}
  \github{https://git.io/JLNIB}

}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want. 
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader

\end{fullwidth}


\end{document}
```

here is the link for the logo [logo](https://ibb.co/Bw2h1hV)

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz can you tell how to do that. Do I copy the whole code?

Comment: We don't need the whole code, just enough to make a compilable document that still shows us the header your question is about. See the link in my previous comment for more information.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}


% If using pdflatex:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}

\begin{document}

\name{Osama Younus\hspace*{6.5cm}\lowercase{\includegraphics[width=1.15in]{example-image-duck}}}

\tagline{Software Developer}

\personalinfo{%
  \email{21100013@lums.edu.pk }
  \phone{--------------}
  \linkedin{https://www.linkedin.com/in/osamayounus20/}
  \github{https://git.io/JLNIB}

}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want. 
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader

\end{fullwidth}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you but what I meant was that I want the image on the top right of the doc inline with the name. That would be somewhere above the github link

Comment: The only Answer that works to me!